# fastest and the most accurate approach to calculate string length by defined font

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm calculating text length in pixels ( with defined font family and size ) using two approaches below:

Approach 1:

```js
function getTextWidth(text, font) {
        var canvas = getTextWidth.canvas || (getTextWidth.canvas = document.createElement("canvas"));
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.font = font;
        var metrics = context.measureText(text);
        return metrics.width;
    }

console.log(getTextWidth('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', `Bold 12px Open Sans`));
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

And Approach 2:

```js
var fontSize = 12;
var test = document.getElementById("Test");
test.style.fontSize = fontSize;
var width = (test.clientWidth + 1) + "px"

console.log(width);
```

```css
#Test{
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    white-space: nowrap; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="Test">
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
</div>
```

The issue is both theses approaches return different values as the text length?! and I can't find out which one to use without a hand... and why there is this difference? (I think I did both ways correctly)

I'm after the fastest and a accurate way to calculate a text length with defined font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas element is not consistent with plain html. I would use a variation of your first example, changing clientWidth per getBoundingClientRect().width to get decimals, consistent with the dimensions shown by the browser inspector.

I also made the call inside window.load to make sure the dom and every style are showing before getting the size.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var test = document.getElementById("Test");
  var width = test.getBoundingClientRect().width;

  console.log(width);

}
```

```css
#Test{
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="Test">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the second way gives you a greater length then it could be counting the indents between the  tags. Use `.trim()` to cut off excess space...

```
var test = document.getElementById("Test").trim();
```

or

```
var width = (test.trim().clientWidth + 1) + "px"
```

You're missing a `;` at the end of `var width = (test.clientWidth + 1) + "px"`

Could you provide the lengths you are getting?